# Is there a metal axe handle in Before the Flood?

Tags: doctor-who

In Before the Flood, the ghosts can only pick up metal (presumably this is something to do with them being electromagnetic projections).

Moran, though, is seen with a fire axe. He's stalking Cass through the corridor dragging it by its handle. But the axe appears to be a regular fire axe, with a wooden handle.

Continuity error? Or did I miss something?

Comment: They are electromagnetic, a magnet doesn't have to touch something to move it, it just has to be in range. The axe has a metal part, there is nothing that suggests the ghost has to be in direct contact with the metal part - on the contrary a magnet works by the closer the better but does not need direct contact to move an object. Its physics and the clue is in the electromagnetic part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the previous episode, "Under the Lake", the Doctor poses the question during his raving monologue about ghosts, "Why can you handle only metal objects?"  There is never an answer to this question.  However, we have already seen this is not the case.

Prior to his question, we see Moran using the axe and we also see Prentis using a spear gun (questionable, we never get a good look at the spear gun).  We also see Moran open the cover on the airlock control panel.  All of which I doubt were entirely made of metal.

I would categorize this as an oversight by the writing staff, prop department, director, everyone.

Comment: There is no reason to suspect that the spear gun isn't metal. But yes, I suspect you're right about it being an oversight. Unless anyone else comes up with something better I will mark this as the accepted answer.